# Looking for a combination colour printer and colour scanner

Tags: printer, scanner

I have been using Brother multifunction printers a for a long time.  The latest one is `MFC27700`.  Because it has a colour scanner and does reasonable black printing.  And I have had a separate compact Fuji printer `CP305`.

After the last android update, the new mobiles can no longer print to the Fuji.  The old ones can, because the app is already installed.  And I had promised the MFC to the boys when they shifted out to a flat, which is happening now.

So, I am looking for combination laser printer/scanner for a home office

- Must be natively networkable
- Must scan in colour, at least 1200 dpi
- Must print in colour (and black)
- Must have separate black cartridge
- Must do double sided printing
- Only need A4 printing
- Reasonable print speed, the CP305 is rated upto 23ppm, so no slower
- Reasonable cost
- Small footprint
- Bonus if it can hold a ream of paper
- 220-240V, don't want to use a separate transformer to step it down
- I prefer known brands

Comment: Are you sure you want inkjet? How many sheets a month? Do you do full-colour photos, or just docs? Laser will last longer, more reliable, but not be as good on actual photos. I have this [HP MFP M477fdw](https://uk.pcmag.com/all-in-one-printers/74129/hp-color-laserjet-pro-mfp-m477fdw-review), which is no longer made [no clue where they got that price from, I paid less than £300] which I got in 2016 & have yet to use up the first cartridges. Any of the newer MFPs will be similar but with newer 'toys'; mine is Ethernet connected, new will be WiFi. HP all have one setup app - very convenient.

Comment: I should have specified laser, I have added that in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest one of the HP LaserJets for small office/home office.

This link is for the UK, but I'm sure you can find the equivalent for your territory - https://www.hp.com/gb-en/shop/list.aspx?sel=PRN
Just select your price point & feature requirements on the left, until you arrive at the one most suitable.

My own HP MFP M477fdw is no longer made, but I've owned it since 2016 & have yet to finish the original toner cartridges. It has been 100% trouble-free over the past 7 years. Though I see prices listed at around £900, I paid less than 300 for mine, so hunt around.

Copy, scan, print; mine is Ethernet [although apparently it also has WiFi, I've never set it up]. Also fax, if anyone still needs that these days.

28ppm colour or black. The newer ones are even faster.
Document feeder for scanning, single- or double-sided.
Double-sided printing.

Toner cartridges are all separate - C, M, Y, K.
The ones they supply with the printer are less full than the regular replacements - all the manufacturers seem to do that these days. My previous printer, a Samsung, came with full cartridges & when after 10 or 12 years they ran out, I just bought a new printer… cheaper than the cost of new cartridges.

HP have a one-size-fits-all setup app for Mac & Windows, so you don't need to go hunting for drivers. AirPrint, Bluetooth, WiFi, Ethernet, USB & others are all available as options.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Tetsujin's advice, I have decided on `HP Color LaserJet Enterprise MFP M480f`.  The resolution is not as high as I was hoping, but in NZ, the prices are stupid.  This was $1399+GST.

After ordering it, I discovered there was no stock in NZ, delivery unknown.  So I have bought `Brother MFCL8690CDW Colour Laser Multifunction Printer for Business / Education / Medical Centre`.  This was much cheaper at $746+GST, and I very happy with it.

Comment: Nice one. Looks very similar to mine. UK prices down to about £550 on that, which Google reckons is about $1125 NZD. Direct price 650 or so, which is getting on towards parity. I guess prices have hiked a lot in 7 years.